# What is the syntax to define functions under objects

Tags: javascript, function, object

So if I access `name`, `age` the output is correct but if I try to access `bmi` the function doesn't get executed. In chrome debugging console the function definition appears instead of `name`.

```js
var john = {
  name: 'john ',
  age: '19',
  bmi: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
console.log(john.bmi);
```

Comment: In javascript object functions you may also find useful the [prototype call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: you can use `getter` to fetch bmi. Write it like this. `get bmi() {console.log(this.name)}`. Then do `john.bmi`. No need to explicitly call it now.

Comment: Thank u sir for mentioning alternate way of approaching. It worked

Answer (score 1):

You should *call* function with func() syntax:

```
console.log(john.bmi());
```

Comment: Thank u for the response sir. It worked